# Displaying content to search engines but via navigation only for registered users.

Tags: wp-query, user-roles

Displaying certain information depending on if a user is registered is quite easy as I have been using this code

```
   <?php if (current_user_can(‘subscriber’)) { ?>
[content here]
<?php } ?>
```

However, is there any way that this content is visible if somebody directly comes to the link via a search engine or link but not via the archive pages /site links. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect where the user comes from (like Google) using `HTTP_REFERER`.

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "google") == true) {
    echo "Hello Google User!";
}
?>
```

So for your logged-in user:

```
<?php if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) && strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'google' ) ) { ?>
[content here]
<?php } ?>
```

**Important Links**

1. [`wp_get_referer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)